# Restricting Google Service Account's permission?

Tags: google-api, google-bigquery

I am going through Google's [OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) Guide and trying to use Service Account's credential to call Google APIs.

So I've a `data` object which contains credentials parsed from JSON Key File.

```
def get_bigquery_service():
    # ... Read and parse JSON Key file
    scope = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery"]
    credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
        data['client_email'],
        data['private_key'],
        scope=scope)
    http = httplib2.Http()
    http = credentials.authorize(http)
    return build("bigquery", "v2", http=http)
```

Then I will have access to BigQuery API, because I claimed it in `scope`.

My concern is that I can't see any option that allows me to actually constraint that Service Account to be able to use BigQuery API in Google Developer Console. Let's say if the credential file was accidentally leaked to others, they can essentially do anything to any of my services, just by declaring things they want to access in `scope`.

Is there any way we can constraint the permission that Service Accounts have?

Answer (score 1):

So you have project-A and you want to create a service account that can only use BigQuery and analyze data in project-A?

Create project-B, and only enable the BigQuery API for it. Create a service account for project-B. Then in project-A give project-B access to analyze its data.

Comment: Hmm. But I already have huge amount of historical data in Project A, which cannot be migrated to Project B.

Comment: you don't have to migrate data, just tell tell BigQuery that ProjectB can peek into ProjectA data (read permissions)

Comment: Note that you have two options to grant read access: (1) you can add Project B's service account as a Project Reader in Project A. This will give read access to all of Project A's datasets as well as read access to Project A's project state. (2) you can add Project B's service account to the specific datasets in Project A that you want to share. This will give read access to just those datasets. In either case, project B's service account will submit query jobs to project B that reads tables in project A. You will need to use fully qualified table references, i.e., "[projectA:dataset.table]".